# ngOnInit() keeps running for a while after navigating to another route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an `Angular 5` application, Now I have a component called **Solution** which gets data from another component.

It works fine but the problem happens when I press **Reload** button of the browser, so *there is no data sent to the component*, so I put *an if statement* to check is the data equal to undefined, then it will redirect to the home page.

Actually it works and it redirects to the home page but the navigating process takes a while to redirect and meanwhile, the rest of the Solution component keeps loading and gets all variables equal to undefined so that any count function or toFixed() function in the HTML will return errors in the console.

I solved that with a **workaround** to put the rest of the `ngInOnIt` in the else statement of the if condition I mentioned before and `*ngIf` statement in the `HTML` to check for the data coming from the service.It worked but it isn't of course the best approach.

```
 export class SolutionComponent implements OnInit {
    res;
    solutionData = new SolutionData()
    constructor(private SolutionService: GetSolutionService,
        private http: Http,
        private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.res = this.SolutionService.response;
        if (this.res === undefined) {    
                  this.router.navigate(['Home']); }
        else {
        this.solutionData.Temp = this.res.json()['Temp'];
        this.solutionData.Press = this.res.json()['Press'];
         }
    }
```

and in HTML for ex.

```
      <div *ngIf="res!==undefined">
          <div> Temp Equals {{res.Temp.toFixed(2)}} </div>
          <div> Press Equals {{res.Press.toFixed(2)}} </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What is `this.SolutionService.response` actually doing? Is that returning some kind of resolved promise? With Observables, you could utilize operators and/or `async` pipe to ensure that stuff is disposed/unsubscribed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, it returns the data for the component from a service

Comment: In what format? That doesn't look to be any standard structure in terms of Angular, either `Observable<T>` or `Promise<T>`. `json()` is usually executed with `fetch()` statements within `.then()`. This could be part of the issue. If that is an asynchronous call, you simply cannot just use `if()` to check the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Its not an issue with ngOninit, your ngIf condition itself wrong, it should just check if the value exists also use safe navigation operator to check if variables has values,

```
<div *ngIf="res">
       <div> Temp Equals {{res?.Temp?.toFixed(2)}} </div>
       <div> Press Equals {{res?.Press?.toFixed(2)}} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this is not the main issue, the main issue is that the code continue going after the navigating line, so if I put some code after it or a debugger, it would be hit

Comment: there also change it as  if (this.res) {

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by putting *ngIf condition on your solution component. This will load the component only if the condition is true and other errors won't occur.
something like:

```
  <solution-component *ngIf='data'
[inputData]= 'data'>
</solution-component>
```

Comment: pardon me if i am wrong but using it something like <solution-component *ngIf='condition'> </solution-component> should resolve this. You wont need that workaround i guess.